Extract a string value from a JSON field in GCP log analytics
I am working on building some stats using log analytics in GCP where I am writing a SQL query to extract a value from a JSON field.
I tried few queries but is always returns null. I think I am doing something wrong in the regex.
Here is the sample data
responseContent: ""[{\"caseID\":\"1234fhdvdhkdbb\",\"reference\":\"aeb6c134-13e6-4f37-9507-9d4b7eeaf0e4\"}]""

And here is my query -
SELECT
  timestamp, severity, resource.type, log_name, text_payload, proto_payload, json_payload, REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(json_payload.proxy_details.responseContent), r'reference:\s*(\d*\.?\d+)') as name
FROM
  `my-proj.global._Default._Default` AS logs

Can someone advise on what is being missed here? Many Thanks in Advance.

Actually I was able to solve it. Putting it here in case someone needs it in future -
SELECT
  timestamp, severity, resource.type, log_name, text_payload, proto_payload, json_payload,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(json_payload.proxy_details.responseContent), r'reference\\":\\"(.*)\\') as name,


Hi @Shashank Agrawal, I have posted your comment as an answer for the sake of community who might encounter this issue in future, do consider accepting and upvoting it as per Stack Overflow guidelines, helping more Stack contributors with their research. Please feel free to edit the answer for any additional information.

As commented by @Shashank Agrawal,  the following query could resolve the issue.
SELECT timestamp, severity, resource.type, log_name, text_payload, proto_payload, json_payload, REGEXP_EXTRACT(JSON_VALUE(json_payload.proxy_details.responseContent), r'reference\\":\\"(.*)\\') as name,
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
